# suitable clause to return value that is null and not null but others error

Tags: mysql, sql

i try my best to simplify my question.User need to select from the database based on **batch_id**.(There are multiple type of transaction)

Using below query it does not return all the transaction.Should return 116 rows but it returns 115 rows only.The reason why one rows is missing because **to_acct_no** column value is invalid.It means when the transaction occured the user keyed in wrong acct no.My query doesn't include the condition if either **from_acct_no** or **to_acct_no** is invalid.Need advice on which method to use.

Been using NULL but still return the same result since there are value in the column but not correct value.

```
Table

Batch_id | From_acct_no  | to_acct_no
 61619   |  001102125698 |  01278965321
 61619   |  001103568965 |  013052542
```

**query**

```
SELECT a.batch_id, 
       a.effective_dt, 
       a.from_acct_no, 
       e.title_1, 
       b.iso_code AS 'from_currency', 
       a.from_crncy, 
       a.to_crncy, 
       a.to_acct_no, 
       f.title_1, 
       c.iso_code AS 'to_currency', 
       a.to_posted_amt, 
       a.status, 
       a.rej_reason, 
       d.short_text, 
       a.from_description, 
       a.from_amt, 
       a.batch_tran_id, 
       d.error_text 
FROM   gb_batch_tfr_trans a, 
       ad_gb_crncy b, 
       ad_gb_crncy c, 
       pc_ov_error d, 
       dp_acct e, 
       ln_acct f 
WHERE  a.from_crncy = b.crncy_id 
       AND a.to_crncy = c.crncy_id 
       AND d.error_id =* a.rej_reason 
       AND a.status IN ( 'rejected' ) 
       AND ( a.from_acct_no = e.acct_no 
              OR a.from_acct_no IS NULL 
                 AND e.acct_no IS NULL ) 
       AND ( a.to_acct_no = f.acct_no 
              OR a.to_acct_no IS NULL 
                 AND f.acct_no IS NULL ) 
       AND a.batch_id = 61619
```

added code (i followed the structure of the code based on the given answer)

```
 union      
 SELECT a.batch_id, 
   a.effective_dt, 
   a.from_acct_no, 
   e.description, 
   b.iso_code AS 'from_currency', 
   a.from_crncy, 
   a.to_crncy, 
   a.to_acct_no, 
   f.description, 
   c.iso_code AS 'to_currency', 
   a.to_posted_amt, 
   a.status, 
   a.rej_reason, 
   d.short_text, 
   a.from_description, 
   a.from_amt, 
   a.batch_tran_id, 
   d.error_text 
FROM   gb_batch_tfr_trans a
INNER JOIN ad_gb_crncy b ON a.from_crncy = b.crncy_id
INNER JOIN ad_gb_crncy c ON a.to_crncy = c.crncy_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pc_ov_error d ON  a.rej_reason = d.error_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN gl_acct e ON a.from_acct_no = e.acct_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN gl_acct f ON a.to_acct_no = f.acct_no
WHERE a.status IN ( 'rejected' ) 
   AND a.batch_id = 61619
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you are using inner joins with tables "dp_acct" and "ln_acct".
Try:

```
SELECT a.batch_id, 
       a.effective_dt, 
       a.from_acct_no, 
       e.title_1, 
       b.iso_code AS 'from_currency', 
       a.from_crncy, 
       a.to_crncy, 
       a.to_acct_no, 
       f.title_1, 
       c.iso_code AS 'to_currency', 
       a.to_posted_amt, 
       a.status, 
       a.rej_reason, 
       d.short_text, 
       a.from_description, 
       a.from_amt, 
       a.batch_tran_id, 
       d.error_text 
FROM   gb_batch_tfr_trans a
INNER JOIN ad_gb_crncy b ON a.from_crncy = b.crncy_id
INNER JOIN ad_gb_crncy c ON a.to_crncy = c.crncy_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pc_ov_error d ON  a.rej_reason = d.error_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_acct e ON a.from_acct_no = e.acct_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN ln_acct f ON a.to_acct_no = f.acct_no
WHERE a.status IN ( 'rejected' ) 
       AND a.batch_id = 61619
```

Comment: it works!!thank you so much.but i try to use this code for another acct (gl_acct) and make it union.But it returns duplicate value.

Comment: I would need more info to answer your question. I don understand what you mean by acct (gl_acct). You can edit your question to include next question or create new one. If you have duplicated records maybe you're using "UNION ALL" operator. Then omit "ALL" keyword. You can also read about joins http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zt8wzxy4.aspx.

Comment: i add the code to the original answer.but i followed the structure from the given answer.i already omit the 'all' but still return duplicate.actually i need to union the code to cater for five condition.1)dp_acct and ln_acct 2) gl_acct and gl_acct 3) gl_acct and dp_acct 4) gl_acct and ln_acct 5) dp_acct and gl_acct. When user enter any batch id,it will choose which condition match with the batch id.i try to union first two condition and it returns duplicate.thank you so much for your help